# DriveApp createFile add undefined to file

Tags: javascript, file, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I want to create a file with google AppMaker using DriveApp. First i have created a String with the content of my file and then i use

```
var file = DriveApp.createFile("file.scl",content,MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
```

All content is generated like that

```
var content = "";
content = content + "First line \r\n";
content = content + "Second line \r\n";
content = content + "End";
```

The problem is when i open the created file the word "undefined" is added to the start of the first line. The content of the file:

```
undefinedFirst line
Second line
End
```

I have tried to remove the extension (.scl), replace with another extension, create a blob, change the MimeType, remove special char like "\r\n" but the "undefined" does not want to leave.

I d'ont know when and why this "undefined" is added to the file and i did not find any issue on the web.

Anyone have a suggestion ?

thanks.

Comment: Can you please add the whole logic of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My final content string is a concatenation of many string and one string was not initialized as a string. (
Yes, just that)

I have just add << = "" >> to make << var aString = "";>>

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems like there might be a typo in your code. Although, your example looks good, perhaps your code has a typo. Try using this syntax instead:

```
var content = "";
content += "First line \r\n";
content += "Second line \r\n";
content += "End";
```

Comment: Thanks, I have retry with the new typo but the problem persists. The "undefined" appears when the file is created. I can remove it with a .replace("undefined","") after the creation of the file but it is not really clean

Comment: @HugoBricoult FYI, I just tested the process using your original code and it works fine; Hence, there is definitely something wrong with your logic somewhere.